# Dynamically bind dropdown with month names

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, dropdown

I place a dropdownlist into my web page, then add following code to bind items to dropdown list within the page load event.

In this case is a dropdownlist with month names.

On this dropdownlist when the month changes, the previous months are no longer displayed and the previous month is no longer shown after the day 20th of the following month.

How can I also exclude from the list the months following the one on the list?

E.G.

At this time in the dropdownlist month list I have the months included from February to December

After the twentieth day of month February I will have in dropdownlist the months included from March to December

The question is to see only March in dropdownlist month and not see following months (from April to December...)

```
public partial class DD_Monthbind : Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            Monthbind();
        }
    }

    private void Monthbind()
    {
        DateTimeFormatInfo info = DateTimeFormatInfo.GetInstance(null);
        int currentMonth = DateTime.Now.Month;

        for (int i = 1; i < 13; i++)
        {
            bool isMonthInPast = ((i + 1) < currentMonth) || (i + 1 == currentMonth && DateTime.Now.Day > 20);

            if (!isMonthInPast)
                DropDownList1.Items.Add(new ListItem(info.GetMonthName(i), i.ToString()));
        }
    }
}
```

**update**

```
private void Monthbind()
{
    DateTimeFormatInfo info = DateTimeFormatInfo.GetInstance(null);
    int currentMonth = DateTime.Now.Month;
    for (int i = 1; i < 13; i++)
    {
        bool isMonthInPast = (i < currentMonth) || (i == currentMonth && DateTime.Now.Day > 20);
        if (!isMonthInPast)
        {
            DropDownList1.Items.Add(new ListItem(info.GetMonthName(i), i.ToString()));
        }
    }
    foreach (ListItem item in DropDownList1.Items)
    {
        if (DropDownList1.Items.IndexOf(item) != 0)
        {
            item.Enabled = false;
        }

    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: What's the point of a dropdownlist with only one option? In any case, just check `DateTime.Today.Month` and `DateTime.Today.Day' to see if it's past the 20th. If so, just add one ListItem to the dropdownlist and return, before the loop. Otherwise, do the loop, adding whatever you want.

Comment: @HereticMonkey thanks for reply, pls see **update** on the question... the dropdownlist is empty...